# Java automatically removing the leading zeros when data is fetched from database

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Java automatically removing the leading zeros of the value stored in Database.
Suppose the value is 0000123 . I am getting column value as 123

I am using JPA for the same.I want leading zeros as well

Comment: What's the column's datatype?

Comment: Column type is Numeric

Comment: Well, if the data is stored as `NUMERIC`, how can it possibly have leading zeroes?

Comment: In case you actually just want to pad the number with zeroes, [this](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) should help